# How to find the days that are in a specific month between two dates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to come up with a formula for finding if a month is between two dates in order to then return the number of network days that fall in that month.

Here's an example of the setup I'm working with:

Sheet 1:

```
     A          B            C
1 | Name |  Start Date |  End Date |
-------------------------------------
2 | Anne |   2/16/23   |  3/10/23  |
3 | Bob  |   4/23/23   |  7/4/23   |
```

Sheet 2:

```
     A         B       C           
1 | Name |   Month  | Days |
-----------------------------
2 | Anne | February |      |
3 | Bob  |    May   |      |
```

Where if the name in sheet 2 matches the name in sheet 1 then I want to find the number of network days in the month that falls between the start and end date in sheet 1. So it would look a little something like this:

```
     A         B       C           
1 | Name |   Month  | Days |
-----------------------------
2 | Anne | February |   9  |
3 | Bob  |    May   |  23  |
```

The dates would only be for a specific year, so for this example only dates in 2023. Also, the names would only be listed once so no repeats.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `1` Is there going to be a scenario where start/end dates can span across multiple years, say for *Anne* the start date is *16-Feb-23* and end date is *3-Oct-2024*; so that includes **Feb** from both 2023 & 2024?! `2` also above example for *Bob* has *start date>end date* `3`In sheet 1 is *Anne* going to be listed just once (unique) OR any chance of multiple listings?! `4` Can you also showcase the expected output for your test scenarios

Comment: 1. No, the dates would only be for a specific year (So for this example 2023 only)
2. Fixed.
3. Each name would be unique.
4. Added.

Comment: would you please provide an example where the end date contributes to the number of network days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of this formula is... that it is works.
The main disadvantage of this formula is... that is could probably be a fraction of the length and more efficient were it written by someone more talented than I.

End this formula in Cell C2 of sheet2:

`=map(map(map(A2:A3,B2:B3,LAMBDA(user,mth,query({Sheet1!A2:C},"select Col2 where Col1 is not null and Col1 = '"&user&"'"))),map(A2:A3,B2:B3,LAMBDA(user,mth,date(year(query({Sheet1!A2:C},"select Col2 where Col1 is not null and Col1 = '"&user&"'")),month(mth&1),1))),lambda(sheet1Start,Sheet2Start,if(sheet1Start>sheet2Start,sheet1Start,sheet2Start))),map(map(A2:A3,B2:B3,LAMBDA(user,mth,query({Sheet1!A2:C},"select Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col1 = '"&user&"'"))),map(A2:A3,B2:B3,LAMBDA(user,mth,eomonth(date(year(query({Sheet1!A2:C},"select Col2 where Col1 is not null and Col1 = '"&user&"'")),month(mth&1),1),0))),Lambda(sheet1EndDate,Sheet2EndDate,if(sheet1EndDate<sheet2EndDate,sheet1EndDate,sheet2EndDate))),lambda(startDate,endDate,networkDays(startdate,endDate)))`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

---

**Notes**

- the formula automatically populates rows on sheet 2
- processing logic is:

  - find a match for the user name
  - return the StartDate from Sheet1, and the EndDate from Sheet 1
  - calculate the start date of the month in Column B of Sheet2

    - Year = taken from the Sheet1Startdate and Sheet1EndDate
    - Month = "month(B2&1)" where B2 = the text string in Column B
    - Day = 1
  - calculate the end date of the month in Column B of Sheet2 using `EOMONTH(startdate,0)`
  - some logic to work out the range of dates for the `NETWORKDAYS` calculation

    - Start date = if the sheet1StartDate> sheet2StartDate, then NetworkDays start = sheet1StartDate, otherwise start = sheet2Startdate
    - End date = if the sheet1EndDate < sheet2EndDate, then NetworkDays end = sheet1EndDate, otherwise end = sheet2EndDate

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Λ,xlookup(F2,A:A,B:C,),Σ,sequence(index(Λ,,2)-index(Λ,,1)+1,1,index(Λ,,1)),
     month_,filter(Σ,month(Σ)=month(G2&1)),
     networkdays(min(month_),max(month_)))
```

[image]

`logic`:

- *Pull **Anne** dates via `xlookup` & use `sequence` to list all the dates from start_date to end_date*
- *Filter dates pertaining to **Feb***
- *use `networkdays` function by using the **min** & **max** dates of Feb obtained in Step 2*